# Summarize variables beside

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am looking for a solution for my problem. I just can solve it with manually rearranging.

```
Example code:

  library(dplyr)

    set.seed(1)
    Data <- data.frame(
      W = sample(1:10),
      X = sample(1:10),
      Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
      Z = sample(c("cat", "dog"), 10, replace = TRUE)
    )        
    #
    summarized <- Data %>% group_by(Z) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric,funs(mean,median),na.rm=T)

print(Data)
```

[image]

I want the output looks like below, with each function applied to the first col and then and each function applied to the second col and so on. My code does it vice versa.

Of course I could rearrange the cols but that is not what Data Science is about. I have hundreds of cols and want to apply multiple functions.

This is what I want:

```
summarized <- summarized[,c(1,2,4,3,5)] #best solution yet
```

[image]

Is there any argument I am missing? I bet there is an easy solution or an other function does the job.
Guys, thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to post-process with adequate `select_helpers`

```
library(dplyr)
summarized %>% 
    select(Z, starts_with('W'), everything())
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Z     W_mean W_median X_mean X_median
#  <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 cat     5.25      5.5   3.75      3.5
#2 dog     5.67      5.5   6.67      7
```

---

If there are 100s of columns, one approach is to get the substring of the column names, and order

```
library(stringr)
summarized %>% 
         select(Z, order(str_remove(names(.), "_.*")))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Z     W_mean W_median X_mean X_median
#  <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 cat     5.25      5.5   3.75      3.5
#2 dog     5.67      5.5   6.67      7
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Your solutions may work here but are not the tool for hundreds of cols. What could be another approach?

Comment: Same for @Daniel Sjoberg

Comment: this works fine! If you dont need to keep the original order from the input data (like in my case) this does the job pretty good. Thank you Arun!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `starts_with()` to select the columns, instead of by number.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  W = sample(1:10),
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Z = sample(c("cat", "dog"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)        

summarized <- 
  Data %>% 
  group_by(Z) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric,funs(mean,median),na.rm=T) %>%
  select(Z, starts_with("W_"), starts_with("X_"))

summarized
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   Z     W_mean W_median X_mean X_median
#>   <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 cat     5.25      5.5   3.75      3.5
#> 2 dog     5.67      5.5   6.67      7
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>